# Testing org.apache.http.entity.ContentType when the HTTP response content type doesn't contain a space

Tags: java, spring, junit, rest-assured, spring-oauth2

I am writing a test for an authorization server that tests that the content type of an oauth response is JSON. The authorization server is using `spring-security-oauth2 2.0.1.4.RELEASE` and my JUnit test is using `rest-assured 2.9.0`.

```
@Test
public void testTokenEndpoint() throws Exception {
    // Client Credentials Grant
    ResponseBody clientCredentialsGrantResponseBody =
            given(this.spec)
                .authentication().basic(VALID_CLIENT_ID, VALID_CLIENT_SECRET)
                .queryParameter("grant_type", CLIENT_CREDENTIALS_GRANT)
                .queryParameter("username", VALID_USERNAME)
                .queryParameter("password", VALID_PASSWORD)
                .queryParameter("scope", VALID_SCOPES)
            .when()
                .post(OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT)
            .then()
                .assertThat().contentType(is(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString()))
            .extract().response().body();
}
```

When I run this test I am greeted with this failure

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected content-type is "application/json; charset=UTF-8" doesn't match actual content-type "application/json;charset=UTF-8".
```

So the value of the `org.apache.http.entity.ContentType` contains a space between the type and charset, but the the authorization server response content type does not.

Now I could get around this by doing

```
.assertThat().contentType(is(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString().replace(" ", "")))
```

But I feel that there must be a better way.

**Is there a content type enum I can use that doesn't have a space? Can the authorization server be configured to include a space in the content type?**

Comment: I don't think there is such Enum, I feel, though, that your test should not be using the `toString` to compare the contentType. But it is only my feelling. And I also don't know how to do it properly, yet!

Comment: @JorgeCampos I agree about the `toString`, but when I don't use it the expected value has angled brackets instead of quotes and the error looks like `Expected content-type is <application/json; charset=UTF-8> doesn't match actual content-type "application/json;charset=UTF-8".` and I wasn't sure if that would matter

Comment: Yeah I was thinking in a way to test it like the property of the HTTP protocol, so it must have some way to check the property instead of the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the following class from Spring: `org.springframework.http.MediaType`

It looks like there is no space [in the implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/MediaType.java#L105).